# Codeigniter 3 csrf_exclude_uris a site and all its pages

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, csrf, bank

I want to CSRF protection be enabled for all URLs except my bank gateway.
I tried so much to do it by regular expression but it doesn't work.
My bank gateway URL is: https://sep.shaparak.ir/

I want all subpages like these:

```
https://sep.shaparak.ir/PaymentError.aspx
https://sep.shaparak.ir/Payment.aspx
https://sep.shaparak.ir/Payments/InitPayment.asmx
https://sep.shaparak.ir/payments/referencepayment.asmx
```

be excluded.

**UPDATE:**

The exclusion which we add to config['csrf_exclude_uris'] is name of our site controller/method not the site which submit something to us.
In my case i should set "pay/verify" which is the method that verify user payment.

Comment: Is https://sep.shaparak.ir/ the URL of your CodeIgniter site?